# Css slider with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, slider

I have a container with some content based on flex positioning so it is adaptive.
And i have silde block which is `display:flex`.
I want to have only 2 items in a row for my slider. Other items should be hidden.
I don't know the width of container.

This is my html:

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item">lorem100</div>
</div>
```

This is my css:

```css
.slider {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    height: 150px;
}
```

I have:

[image: I have]

I want:

[image: I want]

***Update***
How it works now

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`flex: 1 0 50%;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for your child items

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;      /* just for this demo */
  margin: 0 auto;    /* just for this demo */
  background: gold;  /* just for this demo */
  /* overflow: hidden; /* Uncomment once you understand the demo */
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">lorem100</div>
  <div class="item">lorem100</div>
  <div class="item">lorem100</div>
  <div class="item">lorem100</div>
</div>
```

Example without the CSS comments:

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">lorem 1</div>
  <div class="item">lorem 2</div>
  <div class="item">lorem 3</div>
  <div class="item">lorem 4</div>
</div>
```

## Simple Prev/Next Carousel

To spare you some brain pain,
if you plan to animate your `.slider`, you should not set the `overflow:hidden` to it, but to a **parent element**.
Here's a small example using pure JavaScript:

```js
const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const EL = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const mod = (n, m) => (n % m + m) % m;

ELS(".slider-wrapper").forEach(EL_par => {
  const EL_slider = EL(".slider", EL_par);
  const ELS_items = ELS(".item", EL_par);
  const sub = +EL_par.dataset.items ?? 1;
  const tot = Math.ceil(ELS_items.length / sub);
  let c = 0;
  
  const anim = () => EL_slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${c*100}%)`;
  const prev = () => (c = mod(c-1, tot), anim());
  const next = () => (c = mod(c+1, tot), anim());
  
  EL(".prev", EL_par).addEventListener("click", prev);
  EL(".next", EL_par).addEventListener("click", next);
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Slider */

.slider-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper" data-items="2">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item" style="background:#0bf;">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item" style="background:#fb0;">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item" style="background:#f0b;">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item" style="background:#b0f;">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item" style="background:#bf0;">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item" style="background:#0fb;">Item 6</div>
    <!-- Never use inline style. This is just for demo. -->
  </div>
  <button class="prev" type="button">&larr;</button>
  <button class="next" type="button">&rarr;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u. It works almost correctly, but how to prevent filling the maximum width of the container

Comment: @OlegKalyugin I don't understand... you mean like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/gjqvhLc0/ ? That's exactly what's stated in CSS code comments.

Comment: @OlegKalyugin No voice from you, but I've added another example. Might be helpful.

Comment: I used your first solution. And updated my post

Comment: @OlegKalyugin your new image is totally unrelated to the working and the styles of the slider. You might have some other parent related styles you might want to fix. Could you please share a minimal jsfiddle.net so I can take a look?

Comment: I have tested some. If i delete text from element, my problem is solved. Element code https://jsfiddle.net/6h52ykoL/38/

Comment: `.slide-elemetn` ? you mean `.slide-element`?

Comment: @OlegKalyugin please show the example with the issue than. Anyways.... what means `48%` is that some magic number? `margin: 10px` but than a flex with `48%` basis cannot ever work.

Comment: Simply use your `slides` as un-styled placeholders. Style instead (as "cards") some inner elements and you're pretty much done. And don't forget to use some quick CSS reset like `* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
`

Comment: Or use a margin defined in %, not in px

Comment: Also, welcome to the responsive web era. Stop using `width` defined in PX, like i.e: for your image elements. Anyways. As you see your issue is unrelated to your question. You have other styles messing around your design.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242211/discussion-between-oleg-kalyugin-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score -1):

[flex: 1 0 50%;](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.item{
  height: 150px;
  flex:1 0 50%;
}


/* background color for the items */
.item_1{
  background:#ff0000;
}
.item_2{
  background:#00ff00;
}
.item_3{
  background:#0000ff;
}
.item_4{
  background:#ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item item_1">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item item_2">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item item_3">lorem100</div>
    <div class="item item_4">lorem100</div>
</div>
```